# Getting ELIFECYCLE ERR! 1 ( errno 1), while running npm run electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am getting Below error while running the electron command

The application window is open for a fraction of seconds and closing it.

I don't know what happening here

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bullet-bot@1.14.4 electron: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bullet-bot@1.14.4 electron script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ganesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-27T09_40_29_408Z-debug.log
```

I have tried multiple solutions but not resolved it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is any got the same issue?